# .Net API JSON Request contains unnecessary wrapper class

Tags: c#, json, .net-7.0

I'm using .net 7 and have been looking into this quite a bit but I cannot seem to find what I'm looking for.

I have a request with this structure, note the data "wrapper" class:

```json
{
    "data":
    {
        "productId":"1879",
        "dateTime":"2023-09-06T09:00:00",
        "bookingItems":
        [
            {
                "category":"ADULT",
                "count":1
            },
            {
                "category":"CHILD",
                "count":1
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

And to bind my object in the controller method I need to use two classes
`ReserveRequest` + `ReserveRequestInternal`

```
public class ReserveRequest
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "data")]
        public ReserveRequestInternal data { get; set; }
    }

    public class ReserveRequestInternal
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "productId")]
        public string productId { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "dateTime")]
        public string dateTime { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "bookingItems")]
        public List<BookingItem> bookingItems { get; set; }
    }
```

So I'm just wondering if anyone knows of some attribute or something similar I can apply to the `ReserveRequest` class so I can use a single class like the below and no longer need to use two classes:

```
    public class ReserveRequest
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "productId")]
        public string productId { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "dateTime")]
        public string dateTime { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "bookingItems")]
        public List<BookingItem> bookingItems { get; set; }
    }
```

All of the post requests have this "data" wrapper structure in the controller.

Any help or advice would be appreciated.

I have tried applying the attributes differently but it has not had the desired results.
I have also tried Googling for an answer but I'm not sure of the terminology to use.

Comment: `DataMember` are not supported by System.Text.Json AFAIK. As for binding - using the extra class is by far the easiest option I would argue.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it using JsonObject class for example

```
public async Task<ActionResult> MyAction([FromBody] JsonObject jObj)
{
ReserveRequest req = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer
                                     .Deserialize<ReserveRequest>(jObj["data"]);
....
}
```

and as noticed @GuruStron too, remove [DataMemver]